# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client using express-session

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

```
    const emailaddress = req.body.emailaddress;
const password = req.body.password;
if (emailaddress && password) {
    const query = `SELECT * FROM users where email=? AND password=?`;
    connection.query(
        query,
        [emailaddress, password],
        function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    code: 500,
                    failed: "Error ocurred",
                });
            }
            if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.regenerate(function (err) {
                    // if (err) next(err);
                    req.session.loggedin = true;
                    req.session.emailaddress = req.body.emailaddress;
                    req.session.save(function (err) {
                        // if (err) return next(err);
                        res.redirect("/home");
                    });
                });
            } else {
                res.send("Incorrect email address and/or password!");
            }
            res.end();
        }
    );
} else {
    res.send("Please enter username and/or password");
    res.end();
}
```

I tried using the above code using express-session to store session values. but it gives the following error.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

How can I avoid this. I already tried many solutions. I am following their documentation. Please help. Thank you.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

[image: Code from official site]

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

Else block calls `send` and last line outside if and else calls `end()`.
So if it falls into the Else block, both `send` and `end` will be called causing that error.

You also have multiple call to `next(err)`, without knowing that is the next handler, I can tell you for sure, but they might be calling `send` as well. Which would fall into the same scenario as above.

Answer (score 0):

I see you made some changes in your code after my answer.
Let me try again, you cannot use `res.send` and `res.end` together, you need to pick one. Also you need to make sure you are only calling `res.send` once.

your code should be something like this:

```
const emailaddress = req.body.emailaddress;
const password = req.body.password;
if (emailaddress && password) {
    const query = `SELECT * FROM users where email=? AND password=?`;
    connection.query(
        query,
        [emailaddress, password],
        function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    code: 500,
                    failed: "Error occurred",
                });
                return; // make sure your function execution stops here, as you already called send();
            }
            if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.regenerate(function (err) {
                    // if (err) next(err);
                    req.session.loggedin = true;
                    req.session.emailaddress = req.body.emailaddress;
                    req.session.save(function (err) {
                        // if (err) return next(err);
                        res.redirect("/home");
                    });
                });
            } else {
                res.send("Incorrect email address and/or password!");
                return; // same thing, called send() make sure to end the function
            }
            // res.end(); you probably don't need this
        }
    );
} else {
    res.send("Please enter username and/or password");
    // res.end(); you probably don't need this
    return;
}
```